# Getting a managed metada field to use in sharepoint 2013 workflow condition

Tags: workflow, 2013, designer-workflow

I'm working on a SharePoint 2013 publishing approval workflow that needs to compare if a managed metadata field in a newly created item is set to a specific value. This in order to assign a task to a sharepoint group if the condition is true. I'm having difficulties in finding the value of the MMD field. I've tried to do it in the Term|GUID-way(Term|xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx). But I don't get any values at all.

If anyone has some pointers or advice on this issue, it would be great!

Thanks, Joakim

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet that I have used to set the values in a TaxonomyField in SharePoint 2010.

However the object model hasn't changed too much in this area:-

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.taxonomyfieldvalue_members.aspx

This code is expecting an SPListItem object to be passed through.

```
string labelValue = String.Empty;
TaxonomyField field = item.Fields.GetField(fieldName) as TaxonomyField;
string fieldValue = item[field.Id].ToString();

TaxonomyFieldValue taxonomyFieldValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue(field);
string fieldValue = item[field.Id].ToString();
if (fieldValue.Contains("|"))
{
  taxonomyFieldValue.PopulateFromLabelGuidPair(fieldValue);
}

labelValue = taxonomyFieldValue.Label;
```

You can now compare the value inside labelValue with the value you need to check.